. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host for a local file
I got this code :
manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "AutoClicker",
  "version": "1.0",
     "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "host_permissions": ["*://*/*"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "action": {}
}



I'm trying to test it on a local file , but whenever i try it i got this :
Error executing script: Error: Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.

i searched for the permission and i couldn't find it , any help ?
I tried to run that script on a local host file , but i get an error that i don't have permission

"*://*/*" doesn't include file://. Use <all_urls> and explicitly enable file access in chrome://extensions for your extension.

Ithink the error that you are facing is due to the fact that chrome does not have permission to access your local files.
To allow the extension to access your local files you need to enable this in the extension settings like so.

Open the Extension management page by navigation to
chrome://extensions.

Go to the list of extensions and on your extension click on details button.

Then you scroll down to the Allow access to file URLs section and toggle the switch on.


Note that the above will work If the extension is loaded from your local disk.
You can check if file access is allowed by using chrome.extension.isAllowedFileSchemaAccess
SO in your code you can modify the host_permissons and permissions like so to allow file access
{

   "manifest_version": 3,
   "name": "AutoClicker",
   "version": "1.0",
   "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting", "file://*/*"],
   "background": {
            "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
   "host_permissions": ["*://*/*", "file://*/*"],
   "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
     ],
   "action": {}
}

For future questions the chrome developer documentation would be a good place to start. here
